# Google apps api created users created are suspended

Tags: google-api, google-provisioning-api, google-profiles-api

I am using google apps provisioning api from java (Idm - Midpoint). Whenewer i create test user it is supended with suspended reason weblogin reqiered. Then account needs to be authenticated by sms.
Other istallation of this software is working fine and newly created users are allowed to login without sms authentization.
Is there any way how to troubleshoot, why google marks my test accounts as suspicious and requires initial weblogin?

Comment: Does this happen only when you try to create a user through an application or it happens using their 'Try It' feature as well?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Authorizing requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate#authorizing_requests),

> The authorization scopes accepted by the Profiles and **Provisioning API**s have been replaced by several new scopes. Scopes supported by the Profiles and Provisioning APIs are also supported by the Directory API, but **new applications should use the existing Directory API scopes**.

Furthermore, it was mentioned in [User accounts and multi-domain users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate#user_accounts_and_multi-domain_users)

> The User feed exposed by the Provisining API to manage user accounts has been replaced by the Users resource in the Directory API.

Lastly, please note that the Directory API contains several new features that were not supported by the Provisioning API.

Table map of currently supported scopes of Profiles and Provisioning APIs to their Directory API equivalents and more information can be found in [Migrating to the Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate).